# How to keep "]" for output JSON using Jolt Specs

Tags: json, jolt

I have the below Input and following Jolt Specs. I am trying to have the "]" in end in the final output Json. Can anyone help what I am missing here.
Input JSON:

```json
{
  "node": {
    "3": [
      {
        "name": {
          "$.NAME": {
            ".NAME": "name3"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "timeout": 105
      }
    ],
    "6": [
      {
        "name": {
          "$.NAME": {
            ".NAME": "name6"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "timeout": 55
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Jolt Spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "node": {
        "name": {
          "\\$.NAME": {
           ".NAME": "&5[#5].name"
           }
        },
        "timeout": "timeout.\\$\\[<1-100>\\].\\[<1-100>"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Final Output:

```
{
  "node" : [ {
    "id" : "3",
    "name" : "name3",
    "no" : {
      "timeout" : {
        "$[<1-100>]" : {
          "[<1-100>" : 105 <<< needs enclosing "]" here
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "id" : "6",
    "name" : "name6",
    "no" : {
      "timeout" : {
        "$[<1-100>]" : {
          "[<1-100>" : 55    << Needs enclosing "]" here
        }
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
  "node" : [ {
    "id" : "3",
    "name" : "name3",
    "no" : {
      "timeout" : {
        "$[<1-100>]" : {
          "[<1-100>" : 105
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "id" : "6",
    "name" : "name6",
    "no" : {
      "timeout" : {
        "$[<1-100>]" : {
          "[<1-100>" : 55
        }
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

<<< Just want to have the "]" in the end after "[<1-100>". Tried "\]", but then Jolt errored Out. However "\] " works but then it introducing the space, which I don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue raised due to too many arry references. Keep a space before `[<1-100>]` as escaping for the square brackets within the first spec, and then repeat the identifiers with **&** wildcards as **`&(0,1)`** such as in the following technique to remove leading space while prefixing **$** for the first one :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "node": {
        "timeout": "&. \\[<1-100>\\]"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        " *": "&1.\\$&(0,1).&(0,1)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your answer definitely works with the initial input. I had trimmed the input/Jolt/Output in the Q's. I have updated the Full body now and trying to work with your answer on how to achieve the final output body.

Comment: Can you help with final Operation Body, if name is also present in the input and Jolt. Tried my hands but couldn't get much. Also If you points to some link where I can really try out these details things. Below link has some examples, but enough to crack above things.
https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception